# How to store and read a binary value from a ini file on Windows?

Tags: windows, ini

I am looking for an alternative way to load and save small binary blocks from an .ini file under windows.

I know that the Windows registry has functions for reading and writing REG_BINARY data but I wasn't able to find the same for .ini files.

Obviously the data has to be stored escaped inside the .ini files. But it is essential to be able to store and retrieve this as bytes with any value 0x00-0xFF.

Comment: "INI" files are supposed to be human readable text files, especially if you want any standard INI libary files to work on them. To save arbitrary data, you could convert into ASCII hex format (or Base64 encode as mti2935 suggests).

Answer (score 2):

Once way is to simply base64-encode the binary data first.  Then you can read and write the base64-encoded data from/to the .ini files, the same way that you would read/write data from/to any file.  The base64 encoding will convert the binary data to ascii, using hexadecimal characters (0-F) to represent the binary data.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 for more info.

Answer (score 1):

There are the [GetPrivateProfileStruct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724356%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [WritePrivateProfileStruct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions which will read and write binary data to an INI file.

These do require you to know the size of the data when reading it so if you are storing variable sized data you will have to store the size of the data in a different INI setting.

Also if you do pass a pointer to a `struct` into these functions you will need to be very careful in making changes, because the memory layout the `struct` must match exactly for the read to be successful.

Comment: I know about WritePrivateProfileStruct but it has one major problem: it will read/write the checksum and I don't want this because I want to be able able to manually edit the ini file (obviously I don't have time to compete the checksums while doing these...)